# Multiple Entities with same properties repository pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I have a generic UOW repository pattern. I need to a add a few entities which will have the same properties but the names will differ from each other. Is there any easiest way to access the repositories without having to instantiate each and every entity repository separately.

Here is an example code of the entity structure.

```
    public int Id  { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int OrderedQuantity { get; set; }
    public int FreeQuantity { get; set; }
    public double TotalPrice { get; set; }
    public double DiscountOffered { get; set; }
    public double TotalBilled { get; set; }
```

Entities can be like **AbcProduct** / **XyzProduct** / **MnoProduct**  etc. they will be about 10-12 different entities of such products and cannot be kept under a single table with CategoryId. These tables will be often used and updated multiple times in the database which is why we would like to go with this approach.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Looks like you need inheritance http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/inheritance-strategy-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: No, I know the inheritance approach but for my requirements it won't do because i will be treating each entity individually without any parent entity.

Answer (score 1):

You can make them share a common interface.

```
public interface IProduct
{
    public int Id  { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int OrderedQuantity { get; set; }
    public int FreeQuantity { get; set; }
    public double TotalPrice { get; set; }
    public double DiscountOffered { get; set; }
    public double TotalBilled { get; set; }
}
```

As long as `AbcProduct`, `XyzProduct` and `MnoProduct` implement that interface, you can use a generic repository of that interface type

```
GenericRepository<IProduct> genericRepository;

var abcProduct = new AbcProduct();
var xyzProduct = new XyzProduct();
var mnoProduct = new MnoProduct();

genericRepository.Add(abcProduct);
genericRepository.Add(xyzProduct);
genericRepository.Add(mnoProduct);
```

Comment: Does it map to each table of their own in Database?

Comment: That depends on the exact implementation of the `GenericRepository` and how are entities mapped to tables. If you're using EntityFramework you can specify the table for each concrete class using Data Annotations (`TableAttribute`) or the fluent API (`modelBuilder.Entity<T>().ToTable`).

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can use inheritance. Use an abstract class as base class.

```
public abstract class Product
{
    public abstract int Id  { get; set; }
    public abstract string UserId { get; set; }
    public abstract int ProductId { get; set; }
    public abstract int OrderedQuantity { get; set; }
    public abstract int FreeQuantity { get; set; }
    public abstract double TotalPrice { get; set; }
    public abstract double DiscountOffered { get; set; }
    public abstract double TotalBilled { get; set; }
}
```

and then derives other products

```
public class abcProduct:Product
{
    public override int Id  { get; set; }
    ...
}
```